# .html() doesn't work when page changes or refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a JS that plays a notification sound on the arrival of any new notifications. It works completely fine when a new notification comes, it ***should*** play the sound and it ***does*** play.

The `notification` I am talking about is only an `integer` which is returned from a query through an ajax call. I set this `integer` into my `<asp:label.../>` through the script.

**The problem is** : I have written the script on **`MasterPage`**. So every time I open a new page, or a refresh the same one the `<asp:Label.../>` gets cleared which I set from my script using `.html(value)` causing the script to run the sound again as every time the page refreshes or another page is loaded.

The problem may be is , that the value is not *persistent* ?

I want that the value should be set to the html of the label and also its value should be persistent on all the pages . What should I do for this `persistence` ?

My Script is :

```
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    $.get("AjaxServicesNoty.aspx", function (data) {
        var recievedCount = parseInt(data);
        alert(recievedCount);
        var existingCount = $(".lblEventCount").text();

        if (existingCount == "") {
            existingCount = 0;
            alert(existingCount);
        } else {
            existingCount = parseInt($(".lblEventCount").text());
            alert(existingCount);
        }

        //   if (existingCount == "" && recievedCount != 0) {
        //       $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
        //       $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);
        //       var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificationSound.wav");
        //       sound.play();
        //   }

        if ((parseInt(recievedCount) > parseInt(existingCount)) && existingCount == 0) {
            $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
            $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);
            var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificationSound.wav");
            sound.play();
        } else {
            $(".lblEventCount").html(existingCount);
            $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(existingCount);
        }
    });
}
setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't understand asp.net that well, but on the client side, if you refresh the page OR reload a page from the server, the values will not be persistent. Have you tried using a cookie?

Comment: Again i can't access sessions and cookies value from JS ? can I  ?

Comment: I just read , that I can access cookies from JS! Anyways i'll find a work around! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use DIV ID instead of selecting via class

```
$("#divID").html(existingCount);
```

Comment: will the value be persistent ?

Comment: no need to change value. just try select using ID. I am not sure just try.

Comment: It will not work! It will spoil the css..! Anews i solved it !